# Slack-Winston in Node not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api, slack

Has anyone ran the code in npm for slack-wilson lately? It looks like this:

```
var winston = require('winston'), slackWinston = require('slack-winston').Slack;
var options = {
  domain: '<domain>',
  token: '<apiToken>',
  channel: 'my-sweet-channel',
  level: 'warn'
}

winston.add(slackWinston, options);
```

Then I try this:

```
winston.log('warn', 'Node test');
```

For some reason, I just can't get this to send messages to Slack. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything but the package that you've used is out of date. I recommend you this other package [winston-slacker](https://github.com/meerkats/winston-slacker)